# Adding functionality to a button at the end of each row of the interactive report

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using Oracle Apex 4.2, on Internet Explorer 9 . I have created an Interactive report based on view(s) created in oracle database (11g, Release 11.2.0.1.0) (Workspace = database schema) I am using the value of rownum to act as a key to identify different rows.

I have created a "Download" button at the end of each row in the interactive report: code as

```
select V_DOCPERSON.key as key,
   '<input type="button" value="Download" >'  as "Download",
    V_DOCPERSON.DOCNUMBER as "Document Number",
    V_DOCPERSON."Person or Group" as "Person or Group",
    V_DOCPERSON.DOCNAME as "Document Name",
    V_DOCPERSON.ACCESSRIGHTS as "Access Rights",
    V_DOCPERSON.TYPIST as "Typist",
    V_DOCPERSON.AUTHOR as "Author",
    V_DOCPERSON.VERSION as "Version",
    V_DOCPERSON.VERSION_LABEL as "Version Label",
    V_DOCPERSON."FILE LOCATION" as "File Location"
from V_DOCPERSON V_DOCPERSON
```

Whenever the user clicks the "Download" button at the end of the corresponding row, I want the value of "File Location" to be  copied ,  a "Save as" dialogue box popped up asking the user where to save the corresponding file.

**Probable solution:** I created a column link on "Docname", based on [Awads Blog](http://awads.net/wp/2011/09/20/create-an-application-to-upload-files-using-oracle-apex-in-less-than-10-minutes-video/) thought to do the upload(Files are stored on remote Fileserver, location of which is "File Location") and download to the Oracle directory in the background for the respective "File Location" selected by the user.
Finally display the 'Download' link to the file, asking the user to perform "Save As" operation by the browser to download to the respective location.

Issue is, I am not able to pass the values of the file location to the blob table as it is done via an API.

Any ideas or alternate solutions ?

Your help is highly appreciated

P.S : I am a newbie to Oracle Apex, kindly keep your solutions simple would be beneficial.

Comment: Hello! Where your files located? What Is the "File Location" looks like? Is it URL to file or path?

Comment: File are located on an external file server, which have the  remote server path in the File Location.
I am trying to create a column link from Docname , which will  send behind the scenes, the File Location path to a "Upload" form as mentioned in the video, upload for the selected file will be performed to oracle directory.
User will only see the "download" link from where he can download the file to the location of his choice.
Issue for now is "File Browse" only accepts the Database column type as source, can't point to remote server address by a sql query.

Comment: I don't understand what are you doing. If you already have link to the file, show it on last column as a link. User will click link and download file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I dont have the direct link but UNC path in the FileLocation, which from where I want download the respective file.
As per the Awads blog, I mentioned before I am able to do download and upload as described on another page, for individual files present on my computer. But I want to link the same to corresponding Filelocation path where the row is clicked, as mentioned before perform the upload to the oracle directory behind the scenes , then just present the final download option to the user.

Comment: Look at this blog: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/otn/f?p=31517:15